# How to execute the "if" and "else" at the same time?

Tags: java

Interesting problem:

Change if statement and print out "Hello World"

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(){
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }else{
            System.out.println("World");
        }
    }
```

My solution is to add "!System.out.println("Hello")" 
in the if statement,But it doesn't work, any ideas?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(!System.out.println("Hello")){
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }else{
            System.out.println("World");
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:
I think this works:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        if(System.out.append("Hello ")==null){
            System.out.print("Hello ");
        }else{
            System.out.println("World");
        } 
    }
```

In C:

```
main()
{   if(printf("Hello"),0)
         printf("Hello");
    else
       printf(" world!\n");
   getch();
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println` returns `void`, not entirely sure what you want to accomplish with that code.

Comment: That won't work because Java has stricter typing, `if()` and `!` need booleans.

Comment: if statement check bool expression

Comment: you can do if ("1".equals("2"))  that will always fail

Comment: I would say your problem does not have a solution, because, by definition, control can only go into one of the two branches of an if statement. It cannot go into both branches, unless you're using a loop and the condition changes

Comment: Sounds like an int with a static initializer with a side effect...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Tadaaaa:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {    
    if(!new Object() {
        public boolean foo() {
            System.out.print("Hello ");
            return true;
        }
    }.foo()){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }else{
        System.out.println("World");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is so twisted, its genius. I'm still trying to figure out what's going on

Comment: It was a quick edit! I was just thinking - where is the return statement there? Nice one!

Comment: @pst I think Tudor has done too much JavaScript in his life x)

Comment: Since you're returning a true, wouldn't the output be `Hello Hello` ?. Nevermind, I missed the `!`

Comment: `System.out.print("Hello ");` would be better, as then it would not produce the extra line return

Comment: Just out of curiosity, could something similar be done in C#? I've never seen a method being defined at instantiation this way.

Comment: Oh the joy of anonymous classes.

Comment: I'm trying to understand it, but can't. Wanna add some meta-text?

Comment: @Keyser: The if condition creates an anonymous class instance with a public method `foo()`, and then calls the method `foo()`

Comment: This is beautiful inasfar as it replicates the silly solution from the question :)

Comment: @Jochen Guess where the silly solution from the question was taken from.

Comment: @Tudor: Some more explanation would have been better.

Answer (score 5):

I can offer

```
if (System.out.printf("%s","Hello ") == null) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
} else {
    System.out.println("World");
}
```

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII That's the point, `printf` returns something.

Comment: no what I mean is that `println` appends a newline, `printf` doesn't.

Comment: But it should be printed on one line, `"Hello World".

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Yes, works as intended. (Unless, of course, the sky falls down and `printf` does return `null`.)

Comment: Real question is, @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen have **you** actually tried this before downvoting? Or at least checked the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)?

Comment: @DanielFischer my bad.  I checked the Javadoc but must have looked at print and not printf.  We have only recently moved from 1.4 to 1.5 as our level of coding.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen No sweat, mistakes happen. Java 1.5 has many useful new features, you'll like it.

Comment: @DanielFischer I know.  Executors fit very well into what we need to do.  I just never liked the C printf, and did not look into it in Java when it got there too.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work because in Java `if` expects an expression of type `boolean`. `System.out.println` has no return type, it is `void`. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: It wouldn't work even in C where "true/false" are defined in a much more general sense...

Comment: My experience in C is dated now, so I thought maybe it is something I don't know :)

Comment: I'm just feeling pedantic this morning ;-)

Answer (score 4):

My 2 cents:
None of the solutions, including the orginigal C solution actually execute both the '`if`' and the '`else`'. 
All the solutions presented here execute and explicit
`printf("Hello")` as part of the boolean expression in the *condition*. In all solutions, that condition is false and the `else` branch is then executed. But the actual `if` is *not*.

Comment: Indeed, according to the new title, all the tricks presented are not answering the question. However, when the various solutions were posted the question had a different title and was only asking to change the `if` somehow in order to print "Hello World", not necessarily by executing both branches.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[]args){
        if (new Object(){{ System.out.print("Hello "); }} == null){
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }else{
            System.out.println("World");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Precisely. 'Change if statement and print out "Hello World"'

Comment: Vlad, no, what I meant was that `print` doesn't append a newline like `println` does.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII which is what was requested in the question.

Comment: I'm sure Vlad used `print` insteand of `println` on purpose so both words, 'Hello' and 'World' appear on the same line. There is no restriction as to what you use in the if condition.

Comment: I think we don't need the `new Object()`

Comment: @user1368973 yes you do, it is needed because the print happens in the static initializer.

Answer (score 1):

Switch on the contents of `args` and run the program twice with two different parameters.

Your program will either print out "Hello" or "World" unless you modify the input to `println` in addition to fixing your `if()` construct.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the below code to execute both if-else block statements in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main()
{

  bool flag = false;
  if(flag)
  {
    printf("if block returns true-> now redirecting to else");
    goto el;
    i:
    printf(" redirected to if");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("if block returns false-> now redirecting to if");
    goto i;
    el:
    printf(" redirected to else");
  }
}
```

Just change the flag value in the above code.
For example, if the flag value changed to true then first if block will execute and then else.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `append` instead of `println` to determine if the write was successful:

```
if (System.out.append("Hello World" + System.getProperty("line.separator")) != null)
{
    // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved using "printf" with out specifying the format. the code goes as below:

```
if (System.out.printf("Hello") == null) {
    System.out.print("Hello");
} else {
    System.out.println("World");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one...

```
class Test {

    static boolean x = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ifAndElse();

    }

    public static void ifAndElse(){
        if (x) {
            System.out.println("hi");
            x = false;
            ifAndElse();
        } else {
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
** Try this one **
class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        boolean one=true;
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
        if(one)
        {
            System.out.print("Hello");
            one=false;  
        }   
        else

            System.out.println("World!");

        }       
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {  

       public static void main(String args[]) {  

            if (args==null || new Test() {{Test.main(null);}}.equals(null)) {  
                     System.out.print("Hello ");
            } else {  
                     System.out.print("World！");  
            }  
       }  
}
```

this can work, but a little bit complicate for understanding